# Equivalent of javax.enterprise.inject.Instance in Spring Boot for dynamic injection

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, cdi

I'm migrating code from JEE to SpringBoot. I was using cool dynamic injection in JEE with javax.enterprise.inject.Instance class:

Just annotating:

```
@Inject
private Instance<CCIntentHandler> allMycandidates;
```

Will make allMycandidates be filled with all classes inheriting CCIntentHandler interface in my classpath which then I can iterate simply with:

```
Iterator<CCIntentHandler> iterator = allMycandidates.iterator()
```

Nothing more needed. How can I achieve this in Spring Boot?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring will inject all instances of `Foo` if you `@Autowire` a `List<Foo>`.

So, the Spring equivalent of ...

```
@Inject
private Instance<CCIntentHandler> allMycandidates;
```

... is:

```
@Autowire
private List<CCIntentHandler> allMycandidates;
```

**Update 1** in response to this comment:

> Do CCIntentHandler interface or classes implementing this interface need any Spring annotations?

Spring must be aware of any instances of `CCIntentHandler`, this could achieved as follows:

- Annotate each class implementing `CCIntentHandler` with `@Component` and ensure that these classes are scanned by Spring Boot

Or

- Provide a public method to return each class implementing `CCIntentHandler` and annotate each of these public methods with `@Bean` and ensure that the class which contains these public methods is annotated with `@Configuration` and that this configuration class is scanned by Spring Boot.

More details on bean declaration and dependency injection [in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-spring-beans-and-dependency-injection).

Comment: Thanks! Do CCIntentHandler interface or classes implementing this interface need any Spring annotations?

Comment: @icordoba I have updated the answer to address your last comment

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately

```
@Autowire
private List<CCIntentHandler> allMycandidates;
```

is not

```
@Inject
private Instance<CCIntentHandler> allMycandidates;
```

because we can't select an instance from the list depending on type or annotation.

I've spent some time to find alternative in Spring, but looks like there is no equivalent...

We should defenetly bring that feature to Spring!

Answer (score 0):

Also my answer comes maybe 1,5 years, but actually there is a Instance version also in Spring, also it is called ObjectProvider.

Means in your case it would be

```
@Autowire
private ObjectProvider<CCIntentHandler> allMycandidates;
```

You can iterate over all beans having that type as implements Iterable, supports also streams (via `Stream<T> stream()`), but there are also a few more additional methods.